# Better way to hide a cell which doesn't make a condition (UITableView)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I currently have a UITableView which hides cells which aren't within the radius `(slider double)`. Im doing this by setting working out the distance then setting the height of the cells which match the if statement to `return 0`. However this throws up a bunch of constraint errors and I don't believe this is the best way to do it.

So my question is, is there a better cleaner and more elegant way to achieve the same, hiding a cell result?

**Current Height Function**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        if userCurrentLocation != nil {
            let cellData = cacheData[indexPath.row]
            //let radius: Double = radiusSliderValue

            if cellData.distance > radiusData.radiusValue {
                return 0
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better approach would be to do all the distance calculation before the tableview is loaded, and then put only the valid data into a different array that the tableview works off, so you're only ever presenting rows that are valid.

If the data could change once the tableview has loaded and you don't want to reload the whole table, you can use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` and `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` on the tableview to add new rows in.

Comment: That make much more sense, I shall try and work out how to do that haha

Comment: Sweet, thanks for the advice, will try and implement it shortly, cheers